# SQL: How do I combine tables on a single but non-unique identifier?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
TABLE 1
ID   Value   ValueFromTable2
1    A       NULL
1    B       NULL
1    C       NULL
1    D       NULL
2    E       NULL
2    F       NULL

TABLE 2
ID   Value
1    A1
1    A2
1    A3
2    BOB
2    JIM
```

I would like to update TABLE 1 with the values of TABLE 2 such that the following rows would result:

```
TABLE 1
ID   Value   ValueFromTable2
1    A       A1
1    B       A2
1    C       A3
1    D       NULL
2    E       BOB
2    F       JIM
```

Order it not terribly important.  That is, I'm not concerned that A be paired with A1 or that B be paired with A2.  I just need a full set of data from the Value column in Table 2 to be available from Table 1.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a key for joining them.  The implicit key is the ordering.  You can add that in explicitly, using `row_number()`:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       t1.value, t2.value
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

By using `full outer join`, all values will appear, regardless of which is the longer list.